# h2o cluster multi node

Tags: cluster-computing, h2o

I dont know how to create h2o multi node cluster?
I tried to use flatfile but It still dose not work.

Please check the log file:

[root@ptdl-167 home]# java -Xmx10G -ea -jar h2o.jar -name VIPCLUS -flatfile flatfile.txt -ip 10.61.74. 202 -port 54231
07-27 09:03:42.476 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: ----- H2O started  -----
07-27 09:03:42.490 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Build git branch: rel-vapnik
07-27 09:03:42.490 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Build git hash: 47dceae5c504ed6a2fad5de29292509d0b8024cc
07-27 09:03:42.490 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Build git describe: jenkins-master-3905-6-g47dceae
07-27 09:03:42.490 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Build project version: 3.12.0.1 (latest version: unknown)
07-27 09:03:42.490 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Build age: 1 month and 20 days
07-27 09:03:42.490 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Built by: 'jenkins'
07-27 09:03:42.490 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Built on: '2017-06-06 23:26:13'
07-27 09:03:42.490 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Watchdog Build git branch: (unknown)
07-27 09:03:42.490 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Watchdog Build git hash: (unknown)
07-27 09:03:42.490 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Watchdog Build git describe: (unknown)
07-27 09:03:42.490 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Watchdog Build project version: (unknown)
07-27 09:03:42.490 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Watchdog Built by: (unknown)
07-27 09:03:42.490 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Watchdog Built on: (unknown)
07-27 09:03:42.491 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Processed H2O arguments: [-name, VIPCLUS, -flatfile, flatfile.txt, -ip, 10.61.74.202, -port, 54231]
07-27 09:03:42.491 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Java availableProcessors: 8
07-27 09:03:42.491 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Java heap totalMemory: 238.0 MB
07-27 09:03:42.491 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Java heap maxMemory: 8.89 GB
07-27 09:03:42.491 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Java version: Java 1.8.0_121 (from Oracle Corporation)
07-27 09:03:42.491 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: JVM launch parameters: [-Xmx10G, -ea]
07-27 09:03:42.491 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: OS version: Linux 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 (amd64)
07-27 09:03:42.491 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Machine physical memory: 15.44 GB
07-27 09:03:42.491 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: X-h2o-cluster-id: 1501121020922
07-27 09:03:42.491 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: User name: 'root'
07-27 09:03:42.491 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: IPv6 stack selected: false
07-27 09:03:42.492 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: enp0s31f6 (enp0s31f6), fe80:0:0:0:f71d:d7d1:c1e9:a164%enp0s31f6
07-27 09:03:42.492 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: enp0s31f6 (enp0s31f6), 10.61.74.202
07-27 09:03:42.492 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: lo (lo), 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo
07-27 09:03:42.492 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: lo (lo), 127.0.0.1
07-27 09:03:42.492 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: H2O node running in unencrypted mode.
07-27 09:03:42.493 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Internal communication uses port: 54232
07-27 09:03:42.493 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Listening for HTTP and REST traffic on http://10.61.74. 202 :54231/
07-27 09:03:42.494 10.61.74. 202:54231    13206  main      WARN: Flatfile configuration does not include self: /10.61.74. 202:54231 but contains [/10.60.74.201:54231, /10.60.74.203:54231, /10.60.74.202:54231]
07-27 09:03:42.494 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: H2O cloud name: 'VIPCLUS' on /10.61.74. 202:54231, static configuration based on -flatfile flatfile.txt
07-27 09:03:42.494 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: If you have trouble connecting, try SSH tunneling from your local machine (e.g., via port 55555):
07-27 09:03:42.494 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO:   1. Open a terminal and run 'ssh -L 55555:localhost:54231 root@10.61.74.202'
07-27 09:03:42.494 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO:   2. Point your browser to http:// localhost :55555
07-27 09:03:42.495 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Log dir: '/tmp/h2o-root/h2ologs'
07-27 09:03:42.495 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Cur dir: '/home'
07-27 09:03:42.504 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: HDFS subsystem successfully initialized
07-27 09:03:42.506 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: S3 subsystem successfully initialized
07-27 09:03:42.506 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Flow dir: '/root/h2oflows'
07-27 09:03:42.513 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Cloud of size 1 formed [ptdl-167.viettel.com.vn/10.61.74.202:54231]
07-27 09:03:42.519 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Registered parsers: [GUESS, ARFF, XLS, SVMLight, AVRO, PARQUET, CSV]
07-27 09:03:42.519 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Watchdog extension initialized
07-27 09:03:42.519 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Registered 1 core extensions in: 1ms
07-27 09:03:42.519 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Registered H2O core extensions: [Watchdog]
07-27 09:03:42.659 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Registered: 160 REST APIs in: 140ms
07-27 09:03:42.660 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Registered REST API extensions: [XGBoost, water.api.RegisterResourceRoots, Core V3, Core V4, Algos, AutoML]
07-27 09:03:42.730 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Registered: 230 schemas in 70ms
07-27 09:03:42.731 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: H2O started in 1806ms
07-27 09:03:42.731 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: 
07-27 09:03:42.731 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: Open H2O Flow in your web browser: http://10.61.74.202:54231
07-27 09:03:42.731 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  main      INFO: 
07-27 09:04:30.291 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  #02:54231 ERRR: Got IO error when sending batch UDP bytes: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
07-27 09:04:30.298 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  #01:54231 ERRR: Got IO error when sending batch UDP bytes: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
07-27 09:04:30.298 10.61.74.202:54231    13206  #03:54231 ERRR: Got IO error when sending batch UDP bytes: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host

Answer (score 2):

You need to have all host running and sharing same flatfile

For example

1. You have 3hosts, and create `flatfile.txt` for them:

   `10.0.0.6
   10.0.0.7
   10.0.0.8`
2. You need to distribute `flatfile.txt` around cluster (it is not done for free)
3. On each host `10.0.0.{6,7,8}` you need to run:

   `java -jar h2o.jar -ip <HOST_IP> -flatfile flatfile.txt`

Generally, this is manual process, better way is to use Hadoop/Yarn or Spark (and Sparkling Water).

Comment: Yes, I did all. But I have not seen the cluster start with multi node :(

Comment: Do not vote -1 my question. I tried all your step before but multi node cluster still not started.

Comment: is it possible, that you have firewall, which is blocking TCP connection on ports 54321 and 54322? regarding -1 vote - i think this is good question, no point to down vote it.

Comment: I test it in private network, so fire wall was disabled. (I'm sure because when I install HDP, disabled fire wall is required)

Comment: do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Instead of flatfile, you can try multicast to cloud up.

Comment: Furthermore, the log above shows `java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host` - seems like the network setup is broken.